# Twitter bootstrap 3 responsive but should be fixed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am under the impression that there is not a fixed grid system with the new Twitter Bootstrap 3. Am I correct in making this assumption? I've searched the documentation but all I find is the new grid system that is responsive. The project that I am currently working on does not require the site to be responsive. There is probably a simple solution here.

Comment: Couldn't you just have a fixed width wrapper around the modules? site-container or something.

Comment: Asking about product information, should probably be asked at the project itself (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I disagree completely. [SO] is meant to be a resource for good information relating code.

Comment: @zzzzBov and where is the code with a problem?

Comment: @ErikPhilips, the code with the issue is Twitter Bootstrap version 3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in that the new grid is fluid only. You can create a simple fixed layout with a wrapper like this..

```
<div class="container-fixed">

.. the usual Bootstrap markup here...

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-fixed {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

Example: http://bootply.com/71142

***Update for Bootstrap 3.1***

The `container-fluid` has returned in Bootstrap 3.1.. 
http://www.bootply.com/121222

Comment: except that fluid grid nesting doesn't work the same as fixed grid nesting.

Comment: this is not a solution as the cols will collapse on small screens

Comment: The question is not about collapsing. To prevent collapsing use the 'xs' grid.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this was written at the time of the original question, but the documentation gives the steps on how to disable the responsiveness.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Skelly's answer:

```
/* Reset the container */
.container {
  max-width: none !important;
  width: 970px;
}
```

Read about this in [Disabling responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

[Non-responsive Bootstrap Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/#about)